# How can I print all data for each unique observation to its own PDF or CSV using R or Python?

Tags: python, r, dplyr

Consider the following example dataframe. How can I group by Name and then write all information pertaining to each unique observation under the name column to a PDF, CSV, or Excel file? For example I would like all of Dave's information printed to a file named "Dave", all of Sal's information printed to a file named "Sal".

```
Name  | Score|  Date       | Test    | 
Dave  |  95  |  09/03/21   | Math    |
Dave  |  90  |  09/20/21   | History | 
Sal   |  85  |  09/18/21   | Math    |  
Jackie|  89  |  NA         | English | 
Sal   |  88  |  09/15/21   | Gym     |
Goat  |  18  |  09/17/21   | Gym     | 
Jackie|  82  |  10/16/21   | Art     |
Goat  |  3   |  10/17/21   | Math    |
Ty    |  25  |  09/28/21   | Math    |
```

Cheers

Comment: Python and R? For what language do you want an answer? (I take it by Python you include Pandas.)

Comment: Please do the necessary [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) on a language/library and implementation, and make an earnest attempt. Return with *specific* issues with your attempt and not a general, open-ended question with open-ended tools that will be opinionated depending on answerers' preference.

Comment: Thanks for the advice... I've tried searching how to achieve this. I apologize for not specifying Pandas or Dplyr. There may be a better packaged suited for this and would rather keep a clean simplified chunk of code rather than writing several functions.

Answer (score 1):

In R:

```
names <- unique(df$Name)
for(nam in names){
  write.csv(x = df[df$Name== nam,], file = paste0(nam, ".csv"))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just put everything in a loop:

```
for name in my_df['Name'].unique().tolist():
    new_df = my_df[my_df.Name ==name]
    file_path_name = 'your path' + name +'.csv'
    new_df.to_csv(file_path_name)
```